# Bash tee and paste in one line

Tags: bash

Want achieve the following

```
command | tee out1 | some_filter > out2 #the some_filter doesn't changes the line count
paste out1 out2 | sed '...' > final_out
```

The question is, is possible to do the above in one line, using some fancy redirections, without any temporary file? something like:

```
( command | tee >(some_filter) >(???) ) | paste - - | sed '...' > final_out
```

Comment: Is it practical for you to run `command` twice?

Comment: @Mr.Llama yes, i can run it twice... and you driving me to the solution like `paste <(command) <(command | filter) | sed` :) :) THANX! Anyway - I'm wondering about the existence of the `tee` solution. ;)

Comment: You can make `out1` and `out2` named pipes (with `mkfifo`). That way the data will be streamed instead of stored and read. You'll still have entries on the file system though, even if they aren't regular files.